# BufferedRead runtime crash

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, bufferedreader

My app crash when encounters BufferedReader operation. Ive tried to implement the code inside an asyncTask classe, because ive read that the crash is caused by the ui thread, but nothing has changed.

```
public class URLConnectionReader extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {

    String result = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {

        String result = null;

        URL url = (params[0]);

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            url.openStream()
                    )
            );

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

Logs

```
03-02 13:28:43.215  25186-25186/com.example.jsonreader E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jsonreader, PID: 25186
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonreader/com.example.jsonreader.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at com.example.jsonreader.URLConnectionReader.doInBackground(URLConnectionReader.java:38)
            at com.example.jsonreader.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            URL address = new URL("http://www.youth-stories.com/api/all.php");
            URLConnectionReader reader = new URLConnectionReader();
            String result = reader.doInBackground(address);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you a exception stacktrace?

Comment: 0 errors and 0 warnings

Comment: maybe not, just teach me

Comment: This code could be summarized as `return null`, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ArmandoAlberti Which IDE do you use Andrdroid Strudio?

Comment: after the reading i will add some content to return, but now the reading cause a crash

Comment: in bottom bar you have tabs -> choose Android. You will see logcat window - when you application will crash you will see logs

Comment: update your post and add your activity com.example.jsonreader.MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem to get back data using the .get instruction

```
String result = reader.execute(address).get();
```

Comment: But you know that this solution lock UI until you get result